# Does SE lose revenue/kudos/anything from users who disable Google and Quantcast analytics?

Tags: discussion

I've just installed the Ghostery FF plugin to block tracking pixels and cookies on websites.  Do any of the SE analytics affect revenue?
I'd be willing to white-list SE/SO if it does.

EDIT:
Note that I specifically asked about blocking the analytics, not ads.  I do not use an ad blocker.

Comment: I never understand why people do this kind of thing.  Isn't there an implicit agreement with the website you visit that you aren't just sucking content and benefit from the website's owner, but that you are entering a mutually beneficial arrangement?  They supply you with content, you agree to be served ads, be tracked while on the site, and participate in other activities which may result in the website benefiting from your patronage (thus ensuring you will continue to benefit from the website in future)?

Comment: @Won't - I think the real problem isn't that there's an implicit agreement, but that some websites abuse and exploit that agreement with intrusive advertisements and ad-blockers are one way for us to redress the balance. Having said that, I I've never been bothered by the ads on the StackExchange family, and it only takes 200 rep for them to go away so I've never had an issue here.

Comment: @RivieraKid: "intrusive advertisements?" Nonsense.  The only place a website can show ads is on their website.  If they are annoying (very possible), then don't go there.

Comment: @Won't: The *one* thing that drives me to block such things is when it slows down or otherwise degrades the experience of the site. I don't mind ads or tracking pixels as such, but I do mind if some crappy third-party server is making it impossible to even view the site. (I've had no problems on SE sites with this, for what it's worth)

Comment: @Won't, you clearly have a higher tolerance for advertisements than some people; or maybe they have a lower tolerance than you. Either way, @AUSteve was asking how he could respect that implicit agreement for SE/SO. Besides, it's not exactly rocket science to use ads to serve [malware](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ads+serving+malware) - if people like Google either can't or won't prevent malicious ads being served from their ad network, don't you think it makes sense to take responsibility for protecting yourself?

Comment: @RivieraKid: Honestly, how could you *possibly* think I was saying that serving malware was an acceptable part of this implicit agreement?  I don't honestly care about people's tolerance levels for advertisements.  If you don't like it, don't go there.  There are plenty of sites I avoid because of annoying ads, annoying javascript, annoying design, annoying malware, etc etc.

Comment: @Won't - I mean no offense, but I did not say that you thought that malware was part of the implicit agreement. It may be an extreme example, but it _is_ a legitimate reason for wanting to block ads. Besides, we've kinda gone off on a bit of a tangent here. The tragedy is that my opinion isn't a million miles away from yours - the ads on SE don't bother me, so I don't care that they are there, and I visit every day. If I have a problem with a site, I either don't go there, or I use Chrome's Incognito mode to limit the potential usefulness of tracking me.

Comment: @RivieraKid: Agreed.

Comment: Note that my question was specifically about blocking the analytics, I am not using an ad blocker.  Ad servers can to their own hit counting. You'll also notice that I would be happy to allow analytics on SE/SO if it was impacting revenue.  Its the tracking for trackings sake I'm not a fan of.

Comment: @won worst of all, *the annoying community moderators...*

Comment: Worth to mention that installing this extension might [cause the global Stack Exchange search to break](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156046/network-wide-stackexchange-search-is-broken-with-uncaught-typeerror-undefined).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I've just installed the Ghostery FF plugin to block tracking pixels and cookies on websites. Do any of the SE analytics affect revenue? I'd be willing to white-list SE/SO if it does.

Indirectly; we use two forms of traffic monitoring:

1. **Quantcast**

   Public to anyone at http://www.quantcast.com/stackexchange.com

   `http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js`
   `http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif`
2. **Google Analytics**

   Private, though community moderators have access to this data via the analytics tab of the community moderator pages

   `http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js`

Part of the reason we are credible to the outside world is that we can point to the size of our community.

If you enjoy participating here, **"vote with your browser" and allow the quantcast and GA cookies.**

[image: vote!]

That's how others -- including our advertisers -- know this is a large and thriving community of *totally freaking awesome Q&A goodness.*

Comment: Thanks Jeff - SO + meta whitelisted

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments to your question and your clarification in the comments, I guess it's a question of how much you trust Jeff/Joel/SE/SO.

Personally, I'm happy to trust that there's nothing nefarious going on and since I've got enough rep to hide the ads anyway, I don't really care about any possible tracking cookies.

So, I'd suggest, make a judgement call and if you're happy to trust the SE network, just whitelist them.

Comment: I don't like blind judgement calls. While I happen to trust the SE crew, just trusting _anyone_ in this area feels a lot like _argumentum ad verecundiam_, a well known fallacy. We can do better! We should do better!

Comment: While I understand and agree with what you're saying - a sound judgement call shouldn't be a case of blindly trusting anyone. You do have a very good point - I suppose it helps that I've enabled Google 2-factor authentication on my OpenID, and there's nothing in my SE profile that I consider sensitive if it is in some way compromised so it's easier for me to accept the security trade-off.

Comment: It's not about trusting the SE/SO crew, it's about giving away my browsing history to Google Analytics and Quantcast

Comment: I only learned today about Quantcast tracking me here. And I AM VERY PISSED. Thank God I had disabled all Google cookies by default.