# Network-wide StackExchange search is broken with "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-exchange, search, javascript

At least on Google Chrome on Windows 7, the [StackExchange network-wide search](https://stackexchange.com/search) ("Search the Stack") is currently broken.

In the browser console there is a JavaScript error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

It seems to be a problem related to calling a Google JavaScript API. Here's the relevant code as shown in the console:

[image: StackExchange Search error]

Comment: Can't repro. Did you clear your cache?

Comment: Can't repro either. I see an error "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL http://www.google.com/cse? ..." but it still appears to work.

Comment: Maybe your browser/proxy/firewall block the request for the JS file holding the Google custom search code.

Comment: @Mat: I did try Control + F5.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Hmm possible. I get the same problem with Firefox and I am behind a captive portal, but I haven't noticed anything similar with any other sites yet. Oddly it does work fine in Opera, Safari and Internet Explorer 10!

Comment: Can you track the requests sent to the server in Firebug and see if any request is blocked or lost? Edit: oh.. extension of course! :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After seeing that nobody else has this problem I went through my browser extensions one by one.

It turned out that the popular privacy extension [Ghostery 4.0.0](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij) was responsible!

I'm now looking for a solution ...

So Ghostery does in fact explicitly bock Google AJAX Search API.

I'm not exactly sure why but [they have a page on it](https://www.ghostery.com/apps/google_custom_search_engine) that doesn't seem to really give a reason. There's also a topic in Ghostery's forum which isn't very informative either:

> [Ghostery breaks Google custom searches](https://getsatisfaction.com/ghostery/topics/ghostery_breaks_google_custom_searches)

**There are two ways to address this:**

1. Turn off the block on Google AJAX Search API *for all sites*:

   [image: Ghostery Trackers Widgets]
2. Whitelist `http://stackexchange.com/search` *for all trackers*:

   [image: Ghostery Whitelisted Sites]

Comment: Well, can't you whitelist Stack Exchange and Google domains?