# Can I search for a quoted word?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, search, special-characters

I'm trying to find duplicates of this question:

[What is the etymology of "word!"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222018/what-is-the-etymology-of-word)

Searching for `word` on ELU is fruitless, as this word is obviously used all the time on that site; I just want to find questions that have the word *word* in quotes. I tried searching for `"'word'"` and `'"word"'`, but they both matched questions that didn't have the word in quotes.

Comment: [That mean ol' Haney](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247197/150235)

Comment: Someone else somehow managed to find the dupe I was looking for.

Comment: I found it independently by searching for [\[etymology\] title:word closed:0](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&pagesize=50&q=%5betymology%5d%20title%3aword%20closed%3a0) and then telling my browser to search for `"word` in the 5 result pages. Doable in this case, but decidedly awkward.

Comment: SEDE probably can help, as a workaround: http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/265808

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately this cannot be done effectively. Let me try to explain why.

Search is mostly about inverted indexes. We index a post by the words in that post. So, if the Post had the body:

> Let's talk about searching for stuff

We'd index it at each of those words - known as terms.

We don't want you to have to type exactly the correct words to get good results, so we employ some normalization to breaking the documents down into terms. One thing we do is stem: `searching` becomes `search` so that a search for either term contains this result. This makes for a better experience.

Another thing that we do is tokenize (break the document into terms) by removing special characters and most punctuation. If we had:

> This is an "exact" quoted sentence

We'd break it into `this`, `is`, `an`, `exact`, `quote` (notice the stemming), and `sentence`.

What you're proposing is leaving quotes in play, such that we'd break it into `"exact"`. This could be done for a single word that is surrounded by quotes, but now think about what happens with this post:

> This is an "exact quoted" sentence

We'd break it into `this`, `is`, `an`, `"exact`, `quoted"`, `sentence`. Notice how `"exact` is a term and `quoted"` is a term. To find this document, you'd have to search for `"exact` - searching for `exact` would not contain this result. Also notice that we didn't stem `quoted"` so a search for both `quoted` and `quote` would not contain this result either. This would be very confusing behaviour.

Hopefully you can now see why we tokenize things by removing special characters such as quotes. It becomes really rigid and hard to find them otherwise.

Note that we support searching for an exact phrase by wrapping some or all of your search text with double quotes.

Comment: Could you do it like this: tokenize the words as you currently do, and use that to find all the posts containing `word`; this will make use of the inverted index. Then within those, perform an exact match including the punctuation.

Comment: @Barmar = the "correct" way to do this is to tokenize the quoted phrase as a single element (and as individual words), then try and match on that giant element. This is bad for our index size, but not impossible. Just also not a priority at this time.